# variable in php to variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to take my variable in php, and put in a variable in javascript 
there is my code in php :

```
$SQL=$pdo->query("SELECT SUM(nbdeces) as totalnbdeces FROM nombre_deces");
$data = $SQL->fetch();
$sommeanswered = $data['totalnbdeces'];
```

I want to stock the variable "$sommeanswered" in a variable javascript

Comment: It would be useful to know what else there was in this script file and where abouts in the script this code lived

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like

```
<script>
   var val = "<?php echo $sommeanswered; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: And terminate it with a `;`

Comment: @RiggsFolly personal preference.

Comment: @Kevin.a Hi, whats personal preference

Comment: Since the query result is from a SELECT SUM() I withdrew my comment that quotes would be needed.

Comment: if `$sommeanswered` was a string containing double qutes this would cause a syntax error in javascript. as is, it looks like a number, so the quotes are not needed at all.